# 'XCDYouTubeKit/XCDYouTubeKit.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to import a new dependency. I successfully used XCDYouTubeKit before but now after I run the command "pod install" I get this error:

> 'XCDYouTubeKit/XCDYouTubeKit.h' file not found

Here is my podfile:

```
pod "XCDYouTubeKit", "~> 2.5.3"

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'

pod 'XCDLumberjackNSLogger', '~> 1.0.0'


target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'QRCodeReaderViewController', '~> 4.0.2'
end
```

Output of "pod install" on terminal:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using CocoaLumberjack (2.2.0)
Using MBProgressHUD (1.0.0)
Using NSLogger (1.5.1)
Using QRCodeReaderViewController (4.0.2)
Using XCDLumberjackNSLogger (1.0.2)
Using XCDYouTubeKit (2.5.3)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 5 dependencies from the Podfile
and 6 total pods installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

in Edit Scheme - build uncheck "Projectname"Tests's analyze and run , then OK.